# Accessibility of responsive menu

Tags: css, menu, accessibility, responsive

I want to deepen my knowledge about accessibility. So I appreciate any feedback. Please check this code whether it fulfills (hopefully high) standards of accessibility for a responsive menu. **I think that there may be some issues with keyboard navigation – but I don’t know.**

**First the HTML**. Pls. notice the comments inside the HTML:

For convenience I list them here too:

- Wrap navigation in nav tag. Don't use `<div class="navigation">`
- Give navigation a `role="navigation"`
- Don't wrap button in `a` tag or `div`. Instead use `button`
- Give screenreader a hint, whether menu is expanded or hidden with `area-expanded="Boolean"`. Add hint dynamically with JS.

So the complete HTML is:

```
<header class="header">

        <!-- role=navigation to ensure better support, since not all browsers/screen readers will recognize the <nav> element. -->

        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar">
            <a href="#" class="nav-logo">companyLogo</a>
            <ul class="nav-menu">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">nav</a></li>
            </ul>
         
            <!-- By using aria-expanded attribute, the user will be able to know that the button content is expanded or collapsed. At first, we will add the attribute by default and then JavaScript will help changing the value. 
            https://www.a11ymatters.com/pattern/mobile-nav/ -->

            <button class="hamburger" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </button>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

I reduce the CSS part to this:

```
.hamburger {
display: none;
```

}

**Is it appropriate to hide the .hamburger in the DOM?** (I also gave it an `area-expanded` – does it make sense?)

The JS: Here I am primarily interested whether the if statement changing the area-expanded dynamically works as intended.

```
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navMenu = document.querySelector(".nav-menu");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", openMenu);

function openMenu() {
  hamburger.classList.toggle("active");
  navMenu.classList.toggle("active");

  // Not sure whether, this is correct
  if (navMenu.classList.contains("active")) {
    hamburger.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "true");
  } else {
    hamburger.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
  }
}
```

It would be great, if:

1. you could provide feedback, which makes this menu more accessible.
2. you could give me an idea how to optimize the keyboard input.
3. you comment whether it is approppriate to hide the the hamburger with `display: none`
4. you could tell me whether the JS which dynamically changes the Boolean in area-expanded is correct.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Doesn't `<nav>` already have the role of navigation? In my experience it's better to not set roles that are already predefined on elements.

Comment: @cloned Yes, but since not all screendreaders support it, you should add the role attribute.

Comment: Which screenreaders don't support it?

Comment: Your markup appears to suggest that you're using Bootstrap, which already offers an accessible and responsive menu system. Can I ask why you're not just using that?

Comment: @cloned Good question. I read it on a page about accessibility that. They recommended it as good practice to add the role attribute even in nav. But I admit, that is a bit vague

Comment: Hi @Josh I don't use Bootstrap. Despite this, I would like to know which best accessibility practices are to be aware of.

Comment: I'll say that building nav menus that are mobile-first, accessible, and support multi-level (e.g. dropdown/flyout) menus is a non-trivial task, and I don't recommend re-inventing the wheel. This is a problem that has been solved many times over.

Comment: That said, if you want to build your own menu system, keeping it to one level (no second-level menus), you can avoid the most difficult parts. You'll need to be pretty proficient in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, as each of these will be needed to solve different problems. This might be a good resource for you: https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/ also this: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menubar/menubar-1/menubar-1.html Remember that simpler is usually better.